# plugin iframe-resizer get the parentIFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, iframe-resizer

I'm using the jQuery plugin: 
http://plugins.jquery.it/project/jquery-iframe-resizer

OK for resize between 2 different domains.
My enablePublicMethods option is to true.

But i need to get the ID frame in my page contained.
I the plugin example, it's ok but by a click:

```
<a href='#' onclick="if ('parentIFrame' in window) window.parentIFrame.close();return false;">Close</a>
```

Test on the `'parentIFrame' in window` working just on the onclick event.
When i try to get on the load, the parentIFrame is unknown:

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  if ('parentIFrame' in window){ 
       console.log("OK"); 
       console.log(parentIFrame.getId();
  }
});
```

How get the parentIFrame objet without click ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait until the iFrame first resizes, before that method becomes available.

During page load you need to poll to see if parentIFrame exists, once it's setup, you can then call getID();